# Unable to find user in 'me/people' even with 'X-PeopleQuery-QuerySources' set to 'Mailbox,Directory'

Tags: microsoft-graph-mail, microsoft-graph-api

Per various sources (e.g. [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues/1224)) when using the `me/people` endpoint, when I set the header `X-PeopleQuery-QuerySources` to `Mailbox,Directory` I should be able to retrieve *any* user in the directory, not just direct contacts. I've tried this previously (about a month ago) and it was working, but it seems to have stopped working now. I've tried in code and in Graph Explorer, across 2 tenants. I'm wondering if something has changed with this header?

Comment: Yes it was just me being silly - I didn't realise my Graph Explorer session had logged out, and in the code there was a bug. Where are you experiencing it (what context)?